# Question on MVT for integrals + is my proof correct?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, definite-integrals

**Disclaimer**: I do *not* need a solution - just to know whether my proof for the question holds or not.

Let $g(t)$ be a continuous, positive and strictly increasing function on $[0,\infty)$, such that:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}g(t)=L$$

I am required to compute the limits:

$$(a)\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^2g(nx)dx\qquad(b)\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^2g(nx)dx$$

Let $f(x)=g(nx)$. For $(a)$, we can say that by the $\color{red}{\text{MVT}}$ for integrals that there exists $c\in[1,2]$ (or perhaps $c\in(1,2)$?) such that:

$$g(nc)=f(c)(2-1)\color{red}{=}\int_1^2f(x)dx=\int_1^2g(nx)dx$$

Taking the limit $n\to\infty$ on both sides yields:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^2g(nx)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}g(nc)=L$$

I have two problems with my solution: One is that it feels just wrong, I don't know why, but I can't find why. The second, is that I didn't use the fact that $g(t)$ is positive and strictly increasing.

I would be happy to know if my proof holds or not.

If it does - that leads me  to $(b)$. Applying the same method, we would get:

$$2g(nc)=\int_0^2g(nx)dx$$

Problem is this: If $c\in(0,2)$ then we're all good; but if $c\in[0,2]$ then $c$ might be zero, and then my proof doesn't hold. So that leads me to another question - when I use the MVT for integrals, do I know for sure that $c$ belongs to the open interval? Meaning, do I know for sure that $c$ is not an endpoint?

Thank you very much!

Comment: $c$ is not the same for every $n$, in fact it's a $c_n$

Comment: @Momo Interesting. How could I figure it out?

Comment: $f_n(x)=g(nx)$ depends on $n$, so it's a different function for different $n$s, and MVT yields a (possibly) different $c$

Comment: @Momo Great! Thank you. What about my question on the MVT?

Comment: You can take $c\in(0,2)$ in MVT, but again $c$ depends on $n$ and there is no guarantee that $nc_n\to\infty$ without the extra conditions.

Comment: @Momo Speaking of a function that is independent on $n$ (just for the question), how can you know that $c$ is not one of the endpoints?

Comment: Intuitively, if $c$ is one of the endpoints then the integral equals the area of a rectangle with one of the sides given by endpoints and the other one given by $g(c)$. Then either the function is constant $g(x)=g(c)$, or the areas above and below g(c) cancel each other. As the function is continuous, it must cross g(c) at least one more time in the middle.

Comment: @MOMO Thank you!